# Cubic Square in Raster Calculator error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I'm having a problem doing a cubic square in raster calculator. I'm using Arc Map 10.8 and I have an expresstion:

```
( exp1 * exp2 * exp3 ) ^ (1/3) or **(1/3).
```

Where the first part works perfectly I can't gen an result with the ^ or ** function. Results are just min 0 and max 0 or min 1 and max 1.

That does not work even with simple ^ 2.

Comment: Try Power instead

Comment: @FelixIP unfortunately the result is the same...